# Trying to monetize website (Next Js) using Adsterra

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ads, adsense

I'm trying to monetize my website (Next Js) using Adsterra. I tried to base myself on the Google Adsense code for Next js but it didn't work.

Is the code used in _document.js

```
   <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    atOptions = {
      'key' : 'xxxxxxx',
      'format' : 'iframe',
      'height' : 60,
      'width' : 468,
      'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.effectivecreativeformats.com/xxxxxxxxxx/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
        `,
        }} />
```

Below is the code of a component created to insert on the page where I want to place an advertisement

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Adsterra() {
  const loadAds = () => {
    try {
      if (typeof document  !== "undefined") {
        atOptions = {
          'key' : 'xxxxxxxxxx',
          'format' : 'iframe',
          'height' : 60,
          'width' : 468,
          'params' : {}
        };
        document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.displaynetworkprofit.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("adsense error", error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadAds();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ins
    key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    format = 'iframe'
    height = '60'
    width = '468'
    params = '{}'
    ></ins>
  );
}
```

Comment: try this .... load-external-script-from-advertising-partner-in-react-js-app

Answer (score 0):

You Should Try Making A script That Has Inner Html. Like This...

```
var scr1 = document.createElement("script");
    scr1.innerHTML = `
    var scr = document.createElement("script");
    var atOptions = {
      'key' : 'xxxxx',
      'format' : 'iframe',
      'height' : 90,
      'width' : 728,
      'params' : {}
      }
      scr.src =
      "http" +
      (location.protocol === "https:" ? "s" : "") +
      "://www.profitabledisplayformat.com/xxxxx/invoke.js";
      document.querySelector("#_MainOuterIndexJs").appendChild(scr);
    `;
    document.querySelector("#_MainOuterIndexJs").appendChild(scr1);
```